# Why is the last list element wrapping in Chrome? (list with margin inside a floated container)

Tags: css, google-chrome

See: http://jsfiddle.net/WnqjL/

The HTML:

```
<nav>
   <ul id="topLinks">
     <li><a href="/link1.html">Link 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="/link2.html">Link 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="/link3.html">Link 3</a></li>
     <li><a href="/link4.html">Link 4</a></li>
     <li><a href="/link5.html">Link 5</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

The CSS:

```
nav         { float: right; } 
#topLinks   { padding: 0 4px; border: 1px solid blue; margin-right: 6%; }
#topLinks > li { display: inline-block; border-right: 1px solid blue; padding: 5px 12px; }
#topLinks > li:last-child { border-right: none; }
```

Firefox displays the list elements on a single row, as I expect.  Chrome wraps the final element.  If I remove the margin on the list ("margin-right: 6%"), Chrome then displays the elements on a single row.  I am not understanding why the margin causes the list to wrap, given the container has ample width to accommodate the list.

Which browser is showing the correct behavior?  Maybe this is only a Chrome quirk, but I want to make sure I am understanding the expected behavior of the CSS.

Comment: This is also not showing correctly in safari..

Comment: It could be that your float is throwing everything off.. i.e. http://jsfiddle.net/WnqjL/3/ and when it reaches the maximum width of the page, it throws the fifth link to the second row

Comment: It looks like Chrome is giving you the margin on the right but not adjusting the left position of the parent element to compensate.  @Anonymous has a reasonable solution.

Comment: Argh, stupid chrome!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are setting the margin right for the #topLinks instead of for the nav.  I believe this is what you want:

```
nav { float: right; margin-right: 6% } 
#topLinks { padding: 0 4px; border: 1px solid blue;}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WnqjL/2/

Comment: That's what I'll do, however I wonder which browser is displaying it correctly (or if the behavior is undefined).  My expectation was that the floated container would expand to fit its contents.